# Problem Filtering android app based on screen resolution

Tags: android, screen, google-play

I want my app to be shown in the Market, only for devices with large screen. i.e  WVGA800 (480x800, 480x850). 
Example: Nexus One.

I have done following changes in the Manifest file.

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="false" android:smallScreens="false" android:resizeable="true"></supports-screens>
```

After uploading, when i try to search in Market using Nexus one, the app is not showing up. I have also tried with other devices having different screen types.

Any help on this will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the nexus one is a largescreen type phone? I don't think so. If its 480x800 but with "high density", then it's a 'normal' sized screen.

See here: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

If this images is correct, there have been very little or no 'large screen' devices on the market in august 2010 e.g. That doesn't proof anything, but i doubt the nexus would be unfindable in this graph ;): http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Absolutely correct.  The Nexus One has a normal screen.  The __Screens attributes refer to physical size not density and are used in consideration of UI.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i don't think nexus one will be there in that graph, but my problem is if i allow normal sized screen, then devices with 320x480 screen will also be able to access my app? , which i don't want.

Comment: Yes, that might be a problem, but as I read it, the nexus and those 320/480 devices are in the same group. So you've no choice :(